# Protagonist travels using portals and teams up with wampires that ride big black beasts

Tags: story-identification, vampire

Can't remember much about the books. Read them probably 20+ years ago. There were vampires, only I think they might have been called "wampires." They rode around on big black beasts. The protagonist could travel using a portal/doors. I vaguely recall there being a war amongst the wampires and the hero had to team up with one of them. I think the wampires killed their human victims during sex, or at least they could, and that was what my 20 something year old mind fixated on.

Comment: Welcome to the site. You have a good start here. This [guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/62201) might be able to help you remember more about the book. If you could [edit] in any more details that you do recall, that would be great. Every little bit helps us.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This sounds very much like Brian Lumley's [***Necroscope***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necroscope) Novels

There's  lot to cover but it includes (in it's history and subsequent novels)

- vampires (**Wamphyri**)
- vampiric flying beasts
- shapeshifting
- portals (via the Möbius continuum)
- transmission/infection via sex etc.
- War between Vampire/Wamphyr lords/ladies
- Telepathy
- Telepathy with the Dead.

*Cracking reading.*

Comment: Nailed it. Thanks.