# Book series: guy becomes a vampire, creates portals to travel between different worlds to avenge the girl who turned him

Tags: story-identification, books, magic, vampire

I think it was 2 years ago that I listened to an audio book or read this book.

What I remember is a guy gets turned into a vampire after hooking with a girl. He doesn't realize he is a vampire and goes home. I also remember he can walk in the sun and after the girl gets killed by followers of the sun god (I think that is right) he creates a portal to the world they come from. Then goes there to kill them for killing the love of his life.

The main things I remember about this book is vampire, he can do magic, and there is travel between parallel or alternative worlds.

Some other notes:

The girl picks up the guy, sleeps with him at her fancy house in the desert. She wants him to stay after they have been there a while but he wants to go home so she lets him. Then when he changes she comes and gets him. Then she shows him how to become a vampire. Later back at the girl's house he does magic for the first time and creates a snow storm in the desert.

He has some sort of tentacles that I don't think can be seen. He hunts down bad people then drains them using the tentacles. Also, his tentacles are hard, like steel cables; but later on he meets other vampires that have feathery tentacles that can brush across people and drain them of a small amount of their power.

I remember there is a circular concrete pond that he uses as a portal, and has to kill a herd of cows to power it. This is all in the start of the book.

I think in a later book in this series  he creates a mountain fortress that is kind of alive. In his smithy area the mountain produces metals for him.

In later books he comes back to Earth and has to fight other magic users and open taps to magic that are sealed off around the world.

Comment: Elements in common with the Necroscope series. https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/177046/protagonist-travels-using-portals-and-teams-up-with-wampires-that-ride-big-black/177047#177047

Comment: For what it is worth, every time I see this question, I get tempted to post *[Vampire of the Mists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vampire_of_the_Mists)*, but it only matches on a few points.

Answer (score 9):

As OP posted in [a comment](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/178918/looking-for-a-book-about-a-guy-that-becomes-a-vampire?rq=1#comment485608_178924), this is *Nightlord: Sunset* (2006) by Garon Whited, the first book of the *Nightlord* quadrilogy. [An audiobook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00WGIVJ86) has indeed been released.

**A guy gets turned into a vampire after hooking with a girl. He doesn't realize he is a vampire and goes home.**

From [Goodreads summary](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/23464655-nightlord):

> Eric didn't ask to be a vampire. In fact, he didn't even believe in them. Then **he hooks up with a hot babe, wakes up with a hangover, and bites his tongue with his own fangs**. Which pretty much settles the question.
>
> Now he's trying to hold down his day job while learning the rules of the Undead -- the most important being that bloodthirsty urges and predatory instincts are a real bitch.
>
> Upside; Eric has the beautiful Sasha to teach him the ropes, including the magic he'll need to survive.

**After the girl gets killed by followers of the sun god (I think that is right) he creates a portal to the world they come from. Then goes there to kill them for killing the love of his life.**

Same summary.

> Downside; **they're being hunted by members of the Church of Light**, who are determined to rid the world of vampires.
>
> **Then Sasha is killed, and Eric is thrust into an alternate world in his quest to avenge her death.** There he becomes a Nightlord, fights a dragon with the help of his magical steed, Bronze, and upchucks a sword named Firebrand.

As for the other info...

**I also remember he can walk in the sun**

[This review](https://forums.onlinebookclub.org/viewtopic.php?t=40916) mentions Eric being a "Day Walker".

> She changes him into what they call a day walker. A type of vampire that can come out during the day and during the night.

**I remember there is a circular concrete pond that he uses as a portal, and has to kill a herd of cows to power it**

Might have been a single cow, per [this review](https://forums.onlinebookclub.org/viewtopic.php?t=72268):

> I didn't like the part where **Eric had to sacrifice a cow** in order to successfully complete casting of a magical spell intended to show them the location of their organised enemies called The fist of God who tried multiple times to kill them.

The "magical spell supposed to show a location" sounds like a portal of sorts.

**I think in a later book in this series he creates a mountain fortress that is kind of alive. In his smithy area the mountain produces metals for him.**

Eric becomes "Halar the Undying" in the later books, and infuses Mount Karvalen with his vitality. From [its wiki entry](http://www.nightlord.com/wiki/mount-karvalen/): *(the Wiki is part of a Nightlord site which is apparently supervised by the author, so it seems a reliable enough source)*

> According to Karvalen legend, during the exodus of Halar the Undying, when he gathered together those who would follow him to found Karvalen and Mochara, **he filled the mountain with some of his own vitality, bringing it to life**.
>
> [...]
>
> In a matter of days, the spirit of the mountain moved through the bricks and stones, engulfing the whole of the walls, and merging the disparate components–brick, stone, mortar–into a single, giant slab.  Since then, the wall of Mochara has grown slightly taller, considerably thicker, and remarkably uniform and smooth.  **The mountain has done something similar with the city streets, turning mud to rock, smoothing it all over, and even developing underground tunnels for rain runoff and the like**.

If the mountain can do stuff like that, I reckon it could produce metal.

**Also his tentacles are hard like steel cables but later on he meets other vampires that have feathery tentacles that can brush across people and drain them of a small amount of their power.**

Eric/Halar is part of the Nightlords vampires. According to [this review](https://forums.onlinebookclub.org/viewtopic.php?t=71166), the Nightlords have such "strands"; it is possible that what drains life force also drains power.

> Nightlords feed off of humans needing their blood and there life force using invisible strands of darkness.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds a bit like the [Necroscope series by Brian Lumley](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necroscope), though there are some important differences from your description.

The Necroscope series is a long and involved one, but basically the main protagonist is a man called Harry Keogh who can talk to the dead. He has various battles with vampires and is eventually turned into a vampire himself. But this isn't due to sleeping with a vampire girl. He is infected when he sleeps by a vampire's grave and the spirit of the vampire releases spores that infect him.

Harry cannot do magic, but he has access to *the Möbius Continuum* that allows him to move instantly anywhere in space and to parallel worlds. In the fifth book of the series he learns how to raise the dead, but this is not really magic in the usual sense used in fantasy books.

In the fourth book Harry's girlfriend Sandra is kidnapped, though not by sun worshippers but by the vampires. Sandra is infected and Harry eventually has to kill her himself. In the fifth book Harry does go through a portal to the vampire world, but not to avenge Sandra. He has to flee there after becoming a vampire himself.

The vampires do live in aeries (called *stacks*) in the mountains. Their lairs aren't strictly speaking alive but the vampires widely use biotechnology so many of the things in their aeries are made of flesh from living beings (often human) warping into different forms. However I don't recall Harry having a smithy and metal being produced there.

The fifth book ends with an exocet missile armed with a nuclear warhead being sent through a portal from Earth. The nuclear explosion destroys all the vampires, including Harry though he lives on as part of the Möbius Continuum.

Comment: Nope not it, from what i remember the girl picks up the guy sleeps with him at her fancy house  in the desert. She wants him to stay after they have been there a while but he wants to go home she let's him. Then when he changes she comes and gets him. Then she shows him how to become a vampire. He has some sort of tentacles don't think they can be seen he hunts down bad people then drains them using the tentacles. Later back at her house he does magic for the first time & creates a snow storm in the desert.

Comment: Then i remember there is a circular concrete pond that he uses as a portal and has to kill a heard of cows to power it. This is all in the start of the book hope that clarifies it more so someone can help. In later books he comes back to earth and has to fight other magic users and open taps to magic that are sealed off around the world. Also his tentacles are hard like steel cables but later on he meets other vampires that have feathery tentacles that can brush across people and drain them of a small amount of there power.

Comment: Searching through goodreads for this series if i find it before someone else I'll post it. Or maybe i should check my hard drive but unfortunately i don't have description on my audiobooks.

Comment: @Acidrazzor: thanks, I've edited the extra info into your question.

Comment: Ok i finally found it Nightlord: Sunset (Nightlord #1) by Garon Whited this took forever to find for some reason. Not sure why it wasn't easier to search i finally had to go through my thousands of audiobooks to figure it out. Guess i need to put together a list with descriptions.

Comment: @Acidrazzor please add an answer identifying the book then accept your own answer. That will help anyone else who finds your description of the book interesting and it marks the question as answered.